# vector index function R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function in R that looks at the elements of a a list and determines whether or not that value has changed from it's previous state. so for the list

```
2 2 3 2 5
```

the function would return a p-1 boolean vector

```
TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

myy code/pseudo code so far is this:

```
did.change<-function(lst){
  final.vect=vector()
  compare=lst
  for (item in lst){
    if (we are on the first item){
      next
    }
    else if (i==previous i){
      final.vect=c(final.vect, FALSE)
    }
    else{
      final.vect=c(final.vect, TRUE)
    }
  }
  return(final.vect)
}
```

Is there a function to track the index of a list?  this way I could do something like `if(index(lst)==1)` for my first statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in my comment,

```
head(x,-1) == tail(x,-1)
```

is probably all you need. A more verbose version would be:

```
x[1:(length(x)-1)] == x[2:length(x]
```

Comment: That second line is what I needed.  Vectorization!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `diff(x) == 0`, although @joran's solution is faster:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(1:5, 1e4, TRUE)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(diff(x) == 0,
               head(x,-1) == tail(x,-1))

#Unit: microseconds
#                       expr     min      lq   median       uq      max neval
#               diff(x) == 0 532.094 534.726 535.6365 590.5695 2063.874   100
# head(x, -1) == tail(x, -1) 284.914 286.392 287.8685 386.3660 1081.672   100
```